# Error trying to run a multiqyery

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Sorry if its a little mistake. i was using first time multi query. error 1 and error 2 both codes are same except single colon('') added in error 2 insert row. if i echo from inside the the for loop shows everything fine. some time success but not inserted in data base. Thank You in advance.

> Error 1: Error :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'INSERT INTO student_attendance (attendance_date,
>   attendance_class_id, attendance' at line 1

---

```
include("../includes/db.php");

if(!empty($_POST)) {

  $student_attendance_id            =   $_POST['student_attendance_id'];
  $attendance_date                  =   $_POST['attendance_date'];
  $attendance_class_id              =   $_POST['attendance_class_id'];
  $attendance_section_id            =   $_POST['attendance_section_id'];
  $attendance_student_id            =   $_POST['attendance_student_id'];
  if(isset($_POST['attendance_present_absent'])){
    $attendance_present_absent = $_POST['attendance_present_absent'];
  } else {
    $attendance_present_absent        =  '';
  }

$query = '';

         for($count = 0; $count<count($attendance_student_id); $count++)
    {

      $attendance_date_now              = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_date);
      $student_attendance_id_now        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $student_attendance_id[$count]);
      $attendance_class_id_now          = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_class_id[$count]);
      $attendance_section_id_now        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_section_id[$count]);
      $attendance_student_id_now        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_student_id[$count]);
      $attendance_present_absent_now    = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_present_absent[$count]);

      $query .= "INSERT INTO student_attendance (attendance_date, attendance_class_id, attendance_section_id, attendance_student_id, attendance_present_absent ) ";
      $query .= "VALUES ('{$attendance_date_now}', '{$attendance_class_id_now}', '{$attendance_section_id_now}', '{$attendance_student_id_now}', '{$attendance_present_absent_now}' ) ";

      echo $attendance_date_now;
      echo $attendance_class_id_now . $attendance_section_id_now . "<br>";

    }
$result = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query) or die("Error :" . mysqli_error($connection));
```

> Error 2:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''attendance_date', 'attendance_class_id',
>   'attendance_section_id', 'attendance_s' at line 1

---

```
include("../includes/db.php");

if(!empty($_POST)) {

  $student_attendance_id            =   $_POST['student_attendance_id'];
  $attendance_date                  =   $_POST['attendance_date'];
  $attendance_class_id              =   $_POST['attendance_class_id'];
  $attendance_section_id            =   $_POST['attendance_section_id'];
  $attendance_student_id            =   $_POST['attendance_student_id'];
  if(isset($_POST['attendance_present_absent'])){
    $attendance_present_absent = $_POST['attendance_present_absent'];
  } else {
    $attendance_present_absent        =  '';
  }

  for($count = 0; $count<count($attendance_student_id); $count++)
{

  $attendance_date_now              = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_date);
  $student_attendance_id_now        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $student_attendance_id[$count]);
  $attendance_class_id_now          = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_class_id[$count]);
  $attendance_section_id_now        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_section_id[$count]);
  $attendance_student_id_now        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_student_id[$count]);
  $attendance_present_absent_now    = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_present_absent[$count]);

  $query .= "INSERT INTO student_attendance ('attendance_date', 'attendance_class_id', 'attendance_section_id', 'attendance_student_id', 'attendance_present_absent' ) ";
  $query .= "VALUES ('{$attendance_date_now}', '{$attendance_class_id_now}', '{$attendance_section_id_now}', '{$attendance_student_id_now}', '{$attendance_present_absent_now}' ) ";

  echo $attendance_date_now;
  echo $attendance_class_id_now . $attendance_section_id_now . "<br>";

}

$result = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query) or die("Error :" . mysqli_error($connection));
```

Comment: what about putting a semi colon at the end of every query ?

Comment: You're missing a `;` at the end of this statement: `$query .= "VALUES ('{$attendance_date_now}', '{$attendance_class_id_now}', '{$attendance_section_id_now}', '{$attendance_student_id_now}', '{$attendance_present_absent_now}' ) ";` it should be `$query .= "VALUES ('{$attendance_date_now}', '{$attendance_class_id_now}', '{$attendance_section_id_now}', '{$attendance_student_id_now}', '{$attendance_present_absent_now}' ) ;";`

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes. First is, in your for cycle you have to add `;` after each INSERT string. Second, if you wanna use multiple insert, you should write INSERT part string before for cycle and then just add rows with values, there is `,` separator used.

```
include("../includes/db.php");

if(!empty($_POST)) {

$student_attendance_id            =   $_POST['student_attendance_id'];
$attendance_date                  =   $_POST['attendance_date'];
$attendance_class_id              =   $_POST['attendance_class_id'];
$attendance_section_id            =   $_POST['attendance_section_id'];
$attendance_student_id            =   $_POST['attendance_student_id'];
if(isset($_POST['attendance_present_absent'])){
 $attendance_present_absent = $_POST['attendance_present_absent'];
} else {
 $attendance_present_absent        =  '';
}

$query = '';

     for($count = 0; $count<count($attendance_student_id); $count++)
{

  $attendance_date_now              = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_date);
  $student_attendance_id_now        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $student_attendance_id[$count]);
  $attendance_class_id_now          = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_class_id[$count]);
  $attendance_section_id_now        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_section_id[$count]);
  $attendance_student_id_now        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_student_id[$count]);
  $attendance_present_absent_now    = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_present_absent[$count]);

  $query .= "INSERT INTO student_attendance (attendance_date, attendance_class_id, attendance_section_id, attendance_student_id, attendance_present_absent ) ";
  $query .= "VALUES ('{$attendance_date_now}', '{$attendance_class_id_now}', '{$attendance_section_id_now}', '{$attendance_student_id_now}', '{$attendance_present_absent_now}' ); ";

  echo $attendance_date_now;
  echo $attendance_class_id_now . $attendance_section_id_now . "<br>";

}
$result = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query) or die("Error :" . mysqli_error($connection));
```

OR

```
include("../includes/db.php");

if(!empty($_POST)) {

$student_attendance_id            =   $_POST['student_attendance_id'];
$attendance_date                  =   $_POST['attendance_date'];
$attendance_class_id              =   $_POST['attendance_class_id'];
$attendance_section_id            =   $_POST['attendance_section_id'];
$attendance_student_id            =   $_POST['attendance_student_id'];
if(isset($_POST['attendance_present_absent'])){
 $attendance_present_absent = $_POST['attendance_present_absent'];
} else {
 $attendance_present_absent        =  '';
}

$query = 'INSERT INTO student_attendance (attendance_date, attendance_class_id, attendance_section_id, attendance_student_id, attendance_present_absent ) VALUES ';

     for($count = 0; $count<count($attendance_student_id); $count++)
{

  $attendance_date_now              = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_date);
  $student_attendance_id_now        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $student_attendance_id[$count]);
  $attendance_class_id_now          = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_class_id[$count]);
  $attendance_section_id_now        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_section_id[$count]);
  $attendance_student_id_now        = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_student_id[$count]);
  $attendance_present_absent_now    = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $attendance_present_absent[$count]);

  $query .= ($count>0?",":"") . "('{$attendance_date_now}', '{$attendance_class_id_now}', '{$attendance_section_id_now}', '{$attendance_student_id_now}', '{$attendance_present_absent_now}' )";

  echo $attendance_date_now;
  echo $attendance_class_id_now . $attendance_section_id_now . "<br>";

}
$query .= ";"
$result = mysqli_multi_query($connection, $query) or die("Error :" . mysqli_error($connection));
```